# Im trying to create a web mall for a game but when you purchase an item it stops at char online

Tags: php, mysql, web

```
 <?php  
$id = $_SESSION['id_account'];
$connect = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpassword");
mysql_select_db("$gs");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    $iditem = $_POST['itemid'];
    $char = $_POST['char'];
    if(isset($_POST['itemid']) && isset($_POST['char'])) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM donate_shop WHERE itemid='$iditem'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $see_price = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $money = mysql_query("SELECT membership,donatemoney FROM account_data WHERE id='$id'");
        $see_money = mysql_fetch_assoc($money);
        if ($see_money['membership'] == '1') $see_price['cena'] = Ceil($see_price['cena']*0.85);
        else if ($see_money['membership'] == '2') $see_price['cena'] = Ceil($see_price['cena']*0.7);
        $online = mysql_query("SELECT online FROM players WHERE id='$id'");
        $load_info = mysql_fetch_assoc('$online');
        if($load_info['online'] == '0') {
            if($see_money['donatemoney'] >= $see_price['cena']) {
                $minus_money = mysql_query("UPDATE account_data SET donatemoney=donatemoney-".$see_price['cena']." WHERE id='$id'");
                if($minus_money == true) {
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT itemUniqueId FROM inventory ORDER BY itemUniqueId DESC LIMIT 0,1");
                    $select_number_it = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $number_id_items = $select_number_it['itemUniqueId']+1;
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO inventory itemUniqueId,itemId,itemCount,itemSkin,itemLocation,itemOwner VALUES (".$number_id_items.", ".$iditem.", ".$see_price['coint'].", ".$iditem.", '127', ".$char.")");
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT mailUniqueId FROM mail ORDER BY mailUniqueId LIMIT 0,1");
                    $select_number_mail = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $number_id_mail = $select_number_mail['mailUniqueId']-1;
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mail mailUniqueId,mailRecipientId,senderName,mailTitle,mailMessage,unread,attachedItemId VALUES ('".$number_id_mail."', '".$char."', 'Магазин GoodGame', 'Доставка предмета', 'Достака предмета который был приобретен в магазине Aion.GoodGame.by. Спасибо за покупку. Приятной игры.', '1', '".$number_id_items."')");
                    echo "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Your Purchase Was Successful!'); window.location.href = 'shop.php';</script>";
                }
            }
            else 
            echo "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Insufficient Funds, Please Purchase More Credits!');</script>";
        }
        echo "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Character should not be ONLINE');</script>";
    }
    else 
    echo "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unknown error, Contact the website administrator.'); window.location.href = 'shop.php';</script>";
}

$see_item_base = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donate_shop ORDER BY cena DESC");
while($vision_item_base = mysql_fetch_assoc($see_item_base)) {
    echo '<div class="menu-button border shadow"><left><b>'.$vision_item_base['name'].'</b></left>
    <form method="POST">
    <div class="hr"></div>
    <table cellspacing="0" width="auto">
        <tr align="center">
            <td class="tophead" width="50px">Icon</td>
            <td class="tophead" width="50px">Count</td>
            <td class="tophead" width="50px">Price</td>
            <td class="tophead" width="65px">Type</td>        
            <td class="tophead" width="100px">Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><center><img src="items/'.$vision_item_base['itemid'].'.gif"/></center></td>
            <td><center><b>'.$vision_item_base['coint'].'</b></center></td>     
            <td>                Normal:<b>'.$vision_item_base['cena'].'</b></br>
                                Premium:<b>'. Ceil(0.85*$vision_item_base['cena']).'</b></br>
                                Vip:<b>'. Ceil(0.7*$vision_item_base['cena']).'</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>'.$vision_item_base['type'].'</b></td>        
            <td>'.$vision_item_base['info'].'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
    if ($_SESSION['id']) {
    echo'<div class="hr"></div><br><br><br>
    <div align="center">
    Choose Char.:<select name="char">';
                $load_char = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM players WHERE account_id='$id'");
                while($load_char_ok = mysql_fetch_assoc($load_char)) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$load_char_ok['id'].'">'.$load_char_ok['name'].'</option>';
                }
    echo '</select><input name="itemid" type="hidden" value="'.$vision_item_base['item'].'"><input name="buy" type="submit" value="Buy">
    </div>';
    }   
    echo '</form>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

Any idea what i might be doing wrong? It goes straight to "Character Should Not Be ONLINE." I've tried commenting out portion but it still goes straight to that section of the code when executed. Im not sure exactly what i need to do in order to fix it, it's starting to get on my nerves, lol.

Comment: Please clean up that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $load_info = mysql_fetch_assoc('$online');
```

should be

```
 $load_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($online);
```

The code from that `IF` statement will not be executed, and it goes directly to

```
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Character should not be ONLINE');</script>"
```

Add `session_start()` at the beginning of the file.
The value for `$id = $_SESSION['id_account'];` seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I changed it to  $load_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($online); but its still saying "Character Should Not Be ONLINE" it seems like its not reading from the Database. The column exists and is updated when a character logs out of the game

Comment: Doesn't work it uses $_SESSION['id_account']; to get the account id of the account/character that is currently logged into the website. if i add session_start() the web mall fails to load entirely

Comment: Can you output `$id` to see if it gets the correct value? Your query is `SELECT online FROM players WHERE id='$id'`, so you need to make sure `$id` is correct

Comment: its getting the correct $id i did a print on  $_SESSION['id_account']; and the test character id is 1 which is what it printed

Comment: what message are you expecting to see? `Your Purchase Was Successful`? Can you add some debug messages about `$minus_money`?

Comment: i turned on errors in php.ini and saw this

Undefined index: type in C:\aion\modules\shop_m.php on line 65

Comment: ok i saw this when trying to buy

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\aion\modules\shop_m.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined variable: load_info in C:\aion\modules\shop_m.php on line 21

Comment: so this query is wrong `SELECT online FROM players WHERE id='$id'`, as I was saying